# How to extract different shapes from an Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am a newbie in Image processing world and I have a problem statement which I need a head start to solve it.

**Problem Statement:**

I have an image which consist of a pattern. This pattern is created using different individual shapes. Below is the pattern and the individual shape used to form the pattern.

**Detailed problem statement**:

I have 15 unique shapes(image below) using which I can draw different patterns(one example is given already). I have more than 400 patterns. I want to use image processing to find out different shapes (and its position in the pattern) used to generate a particular pattern.

**All unique shapes:**
[image] **Some more pattern images**:[image]

**What I want to achieve**:

I want to input the pattern image and find out the individual shapes which are used to form the pattern and the position the shapes are placed in the pattern ?:

**Note:** I have not included all the individual shapes as the question was becoming too big.

**Pattern Image:**

[image]
**Individual Shapes:**
[image][image][image]

Comment: So you need to detect the dots, and find the area that surrounds each?

Comment: I do know weather I am providing you the correct answer but. I am more interested in the complete individual shapes. Every shape has a different number of corners except two shapes. Those two shapes have same number of corners(two corners) but the positions of the corners are different for both the shapes. If we can use these features then I guess we can detect different shapes and its positions in the main image @CrisLuengo

Comment: updated the question for better understanding @CrisLuengo

Comment: So try that: detect the dots, find the areas around them as individual shapes to be compared, find their outlines, find relative locations of corners, match those to find unique shapes. Fourier descriptors might be a more general way of comparing shapes, if you don't know in advance how they'll differ.

Comment: If you have a dictionary of shapes you could try template matching to find which ones were used and where. That would probably be simpler.

Comment: any link for reference please. @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know which *reference* shapes compose your images, you can

1. localize the central dot which is present in all your shapes
2. knowing where the dot is, find the correct shape.

---

For the scope of this answer I use these images which are already preprocessed. The first image is simply thresholded, for the second I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114929/5008845) snippet.

[image]
[image]

---

Find the central dots is pretty easy on the preprocessed images. You can use `cv::connectedComponentsWithStats` to retrieve all black components, and then remove the ones that are too big. You can find the code in the function `getCenterPoints` below.

[image]

Then you can easily get the outlines (needed later) with a simple combination of this image and the original one:

[image]

Now we are able to find the dots, but we need also a way to say which shape compose the final image.
We can use the geometry of the shape to build a simple descriptor for each shape: we save in a `Mat` 4 values representing the distance of the center from the outline in vertical and horizontal direction:

[image]

This uniquely identifies all your reference shapes.
Then we normalize this 4 element vector so it becomes scale-invariant. Using this descriptor allow us to avoid tedious "multiscale template matching" like stuff, and is also much faster and extendible. You can find the code for this in the function `computeShapeDescriptor` below.

In order to compute the shape descriptor we need also the correct position of the shape center, which is simply the centroid of the blob we found earlier. We basically use again `cv::connectedComponentWithStats`. See `getCentroids` below.

---

Now we know how to find the dots to localize all shapes, and know how to describe them. To find the corresponding reference shape in the image simply compare the descriptors. The one most similar would be the correct one!

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Full code for reference:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

void computeShapeDescriptor(const cv::Mat1b shape_outline, cv::Point center, cv::Mat1d& desc)
{
    desc = cv::Mat1d(1, 4, 0.0);

    // Go up until I find a outline pixel
    for (int i = center.y; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (shape_outline(i, center.x) > 0) {
            desc(0) = std::abs(i - center.y);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Go right until I find a outline pixel
    for (int i = center.x; i < shape_outline.cols; ++i) {
        if (shape_outline(center.y, i) > 0) {
            desc(1) = std::abs(i - center.x);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Go down until I find a outline pixel
    for (int i = center.y; i < shape_outline.rows; ++i) {
        if (shape_outline(i, center.x) > 0) {
            desc(2) = std::abs(i - center.y);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Go left until I find a outline pixel
    for (int i = center.x; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (shape_outline(center.y, i) > 0) {
            desc(3) = std::abs(i - center.x);
            break;
        }
    }

    desc /= cv::norm(desc, cv::NORM_L1);
}

void getCenterPoints(const cv::Mat1b& src, cv::Mat1b& dst)
{
    dst = cv::Mat1b(src.rows, src.cols, uchar(0));

    cv::Mat1i labels;
    cv::Mat1i stats;
    cv::Mat1d centroids;
    int n_labels = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(~src, labels, stats, centroids);
    for (int i = 1; i < n_labels; ++i) {
        if (stats(i, cv::CC_STAT_AREA) < 100)
        {
            dst.setTo(255, labels == i);
        }
    }
}

void getCentroids(const cv::Mat1b& src, cv::Mat1d& centroids)
{
    // Find the central pixel
    cv::Mat1i labels;
    cv::Mat1i stats;

    cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(src, labels, stats, centroids);
    // 'centroids' contains in each row x,y coordinates of the centroid
}


int main()
{
    // Load the reference shapes
    cv::Mat1b reference = cv::imread("path_to_reference_shapes", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // -------------------------
    // Compute descriptor for each reference shape
    // -------------------------

    // Get the centers
    cv::Mat1b reference_centers;
    getCenterPoints(reference, reference_centers);

    // Get the centroids
    cv::Mat1d shape_centroids;
    getCentroids(reference_centers, shape_centroids);

    // Find the outline
    cv::Mat1b reference_outline = ~(reference | reference_centers);

    // Prepare output image
    cv::Mat3b reference_output;
    cv::cvtColor(reference, reference_output, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    // Compute the descriptor for each shape
    std::vector<cv::Mat1f> shape_descriptors;
    for (int i = 1; i < shape_centroids.rows; ++i)
    {
        cv::Point center;
        center.x = std::round(shape_centroids(i, 0));
        center.y = std::round(shape_centroids(i, 1));

        cv::Mat1d desc;
        computeShapeDescriptor(reference_outline, center, desc);

        shape_descriptors.push_back(desc.clone());

        // Draw the ID of the shape
        cv::putText(reference_output, cv::String(std::to_string(i)), center, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    }

    // -------------------------
    // Find shapes in image
    // -------------------------

    cv::Mat1b img = cv::imread("path_to_image", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Get the centers
    cv::Mat1b img_centers;
    getCenterPoints(img, img_centers);

    // Get the centroids
    cv::Mat1d img_centroids;
    getCentroids(img_centers, img_centroids);

    // Find the outline
    cv::Mat1b img_outline = ~(img | img_centers);

    // Prepare output image
    cv::Mat3b img_output;
    cv::cvtColor(img, img_output, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    // Compute the descriptor for each found shape, and assign to nearest descriptor among reference shapes
    for (int i = 1; i < img_centroids.rows; ++i)
    {
        cv::Point center;
        center.x = std::round(img_centroids(i, 0));
        center.y = std::round(img_centroids(i, 1));

        cv::Mat1d desc;
        computeShapeDescriptor(img_outline, center, desc);

        // Compute the distance with all reference descriptors
        double minDist = 1e10;
        int minIdx = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < shape_descriptors.size(); ++j)
        {
            // Actual distance computation
            double dist = 0.0;
            for (int c = 0; c < desc.cols; ++c) {
                dist += std::abs(desc(c) - shape_descriptors[j](c));
            }

            if (minDist > dist) {
                minDist = dist;
                minIdx = j;
            }
        }

        // Draw the ID of the shape
        cv::putText(img_output, cv::String(std::to_string(minIdx + 1)), center, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 255));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am speechless. You are god for me!! its freaking amazing. Thank you so much. your answer is to the point. Thanks again.

Comment: I wanna follow you @Miki need to keep myself updated with your work :)

Comment: Just one help. How can I start reading and practicing computer vision ? I already have gone through plenty of books. But Never got a perfect place to read all about computer vision in detail. How you started ? @Miki If you have time please tell me.

Comment: Break down complex problems into smaller simpler problems. You have a lot of resources online (like SO) to solve the simple ones. Following a computer vision courses (university, PhD, ...) may also help to learn the basics

Comment: you are just amazing @Miki

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dots to locate the individual shapes (binarization + connected components labeling).

Then it is an easy matter to detect the absence/presence of square corners, for instance by means of small windows between pairs of neighboring shapes. This will give you a binary code that you can use to distinguish your patterns.

[image]

Comment: Updated the question with some more pattern @YvesDaoust

Comment: If possible can you provide me with some sort of implementation. I am completely new to this image processing.

Comment: @Hiren: completely rewritten my answer. Seeing your patterns, the case is easy: find the dots, look at the midpoints. And, sorry, no, I am not a free coding factory.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Let me try with implementation. If I get stuck will notify you in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a dictionary of shapes, you could template matching to find which shape is where in your image. Template matching is fairly simple: you compute a "goodness of fit" measure such as correlation, mean squared error, etc. for the shape and the image, with the shape positioned at every point in your image. See for example [these lecture notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Handouts/Lectures/2014_Spring/Combined_Slides/9-Template-Matching-Combined.pdf). If you use correlation (which makes sense in this case), you can use the FFT to speed up computation significantly. Look for example at this [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).

The above assumes that the templates are at the same scale and orientation as shown in the image. If the sizes can differ, you need to use a multi-scale template matching approach, which I is slightly more involved but not difficult. Simply try to match each shape multiple times, at different scales and orientations. Or rotate and scale your image. I presume that, given your examples, you only need to test 4 orientations and 1 scale, so this is a reasonable approach.

The more flexible approach is to detect the dots (use e.g. template matching for that), flood-fill around the dots to fill the shape (assuming that they are all simple polygons), and extract the boundary of the detected area. That boundary can then be matched to the ones in your dictionary using e.g. [Fourier descriptors](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FourierDescriptors/). This would allow you to detect the shapes at arbitrary scales and orientations.

Comment: It sounds good and applicable to me. Let me try it out first. If I get stuck in any problem will notify you in the comments.

Comment: I think I may need a multi scale template matching technique. But I am really confused on how to start that with. implementation of that will be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any examples of my own that I can share. Google does show a lot of hits. For example this one: http://codethatactuallyworks.blogspot.com/2015/12/opencv-multi-scale-template-matching.html

Comment: I am working on your.. I will surely share the update once I get some result.