# Issues while reading and displaying PNG with transparency layer opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am doing a simple reading and displaying PNG image. I am reading a png image with background as transparent. I am converting the image in greyscale and then displaying it. But the converted image is looking something like this:

**Original Image**:

[image]

**Greyscale image:**

[image]

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?:

```
Mat image = imread("3X3_a11.png",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat output(image.size(),image.type());
//    connectedComponents(image, output);
imshow("Output", image);
waitKey(0);
destroyAllWindows();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RGBA image is malformed, or at least is very wierd. On loading I see the warning:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

You can however get the binary version need for `cv::connectedComponents` with simple processing like:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat4b img4b = cv::imread("path_to_image", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // Convert to grayscale getting rid of alpha channel
    cv::Mat1b img(img4b.rows, img4b.cols, uchar(0));
    for (int r = 0; r < img4b.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < img4b.cols; ++c) {
            if (img4b(r, c) == cv::Vec4b(255,255,255,255)) {
                img(r, c) = uchar(255);
            }
            if (img4b(r, c)[3] == 0) {
                img(r, c) = uchar(255);
            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So amazing. Worked like charm :) Thank you so much. waiting for your amazing answer for this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108493/how-to-extract-different-shapes-from-an-image

Comment: can I use `img` directly with `connectedComponents` as the input image ? I tried usin it and i got 29 labels as output. @Miki