# connected components not giving correct number of labels opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to get all the connected labels from a binary image using OpenCV 3.0 predefined method `connectedComponents()`. But after performing the operation. Total number of labels returned by the program is just 2 and the output image is also not displaying anything, its completely dark. I even tried normalising it but I didn't get the desired output. What am I doing wrong ?

**Original Image:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
void featureExtract(){
    Mat image = imread("4X4_b9.png",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat output(image.size(),CV_16U);
    int la = connectedComponents(image, output);
    cout<<la<<endl;
    Mat seeMyLabels;
    normalize(output, seeMyLabels, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
    imshow("Labels", seeMyLabels);
//    imshow("Output", output);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: Invert the image: `int la = connectedComponents(~image, output);`. Foreground should be white

Comment: `~image` is making the shapes also black in color. Now everything is black except the lines and dots. coz of that `la` is 18(total labels) which is wrong. It should be 16 @Miki

Comment: @Miki can you provide me suggestion on solving this image processing problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108493/how-to-extract-different-shapes-from-an-image/

Comment: yeah... I've seen that... I see if I can post an answer later..

Comment: Do you want something like this: https://ibb.co/mfwqfw

Comment: I want the shapes with black border to be white..and everything to be black. then only I will get the perfect number of labels. Almost close you are @zindarod

Comment: I am not sure what you're counting. Are you counting the number of black dots?

Comment: My idea is to get all the shapes from that image.
See this question for complete understanding @zindarod
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108493/how-to-extract-different-shapes-from-an-image

Comment: Yeah I am counting the dots and then want to floodfill the are around it. So that I get the individual shapes.